# Why does sbt give "object scalacheck is not a member of package org" after successful scalacheck resolve?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalacheck

I have added the following in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies <<= scalaVersion { scala_version => Seq(
 <other entries>
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.10.0" % "test",
  <other entries>
  )
}
```

Upon `compile` the project in sbt, the dependencies are resolved successfully as can be seen in the logs:

```
[info] Resolving org.scalacheck#scalacheck_2.9.1;1.10.0 ...
...
Done updating
```

However, I get the following error during compilation of one file.

```
object scalacheck is not a member of package org
import org.scalacheck.Gen
      ^
```

What can be the reason for this?

Is there a way to see the classpath that sbt is using during the `compile` task?

```
Sbt version: 0.11.2
OS: Windows 7
Scala version: 2.9.1
```

Note that the project builds fine in ScalaIDE. (I use sbteclipse to generate the eclipse `.classpath` file. The generated `.classpath` has proper scalacheck entry.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way you import the dependency makes Scalacheck only available for the command `test`:

```
"org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.10.0" % "test"
```

You should use:

```
"org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.10.0"
```

But why do you use Scalacheck somewhere else than in tests ? See [this link](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing) for more explanations about testing in sbt.

Comment: Also of note: use `test:compile` to compile stuff in `src/main/test`. This version will find the dependencies that were marked with `... % "test"`

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Some of the `generators` and `shrink` methods that I am writing are non-trivial. Hence, I am keeping this code along with the class implementation in `src`.